# Start an activity with a shared element from custom view

Tags: java, android, android-animation, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

I want to create a animation between two Activities with a image as shared element, see [Customize Activity Transitions](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)

My problem: In the source activity the image is drawn on a canvas of a custom view :-(

Is there a way to use this image as a shared element or do I have to add a real ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

You can't share the image only, but you can share the entire custom view. This means that the entire custom View would disappear from the calling Activity when the shared element is transferred to the launched Activity. If your custom View only has the image, that would be fine, but if it paints other things, that would be disastrous.

If you want to share only the image, you'll have to create a View (e.g. ImageView) and move the image to it and then share it. That way, when the shared element is transferred, it hides properly from the calling activity.

The shared elements don't actually move Views between Activities, they just share a 'snapshot' of the view as a bitmap and the position of the view. In the launched activity, the view with the given transition name will be laid out in that position. You can use the snapshot or not, depending on your needs. By default, the snapshot is not used.

So you'll need some code like this:

```
public void launchActivity(final Intent intent, final CustomView view) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = view.getSharedImage();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(view.getContext());
    imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = view.createSharedImageLayoutParams();
    final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
    parent.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
    parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            customView.hideSharedImage();
            ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.
                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imageView, "destName");
            startActivity(intent, activityOptions.toBundle();
        }
    });
    setExitSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedElementsArrived(List<String> sharedElementNames,
            List<View> sharedElements, OnSharedElementsReadyListener listener) {
            super.onSharedElementsArrived(sharedElementNames, sharedElements,
                listener);
            parent.removeView(imageView);
            customView.showSharedImage();
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't specifically tried the above, but that's the essence of it. If you don't want to use the newer onSharedElementsArrived, you can create a custom ImageView that listens for onVisibilityChanged. If you have an exit transition, you can also listen for the end of it as well. You just need some trigger that will tell you to reset the state so that the ImageView is removed and your custom View should draw the image again.

In the example above, I placed the ImageView in the same parent as the custom View. You may get more flexibility by putting it into the DecorView, but you'll have to figure out what the global position is and it will also overlay everything on the screen. Alternatively, since I added the ImageView to the parent, that won't work for all parents (e.g. ListView, LinearLayout). You know your View hierarchy and you'll have to choose the best place to put it.

Or, you could change your custom View to be a custom ViewGroup and contain the sharable image as an ImageView! Sounds easier to me.